# How to optimize scrollable / zoomable map with multiple icons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile-safari, transform

I'm currently working on a mobile app using Phonegap. One component of the App is a Map View, not Google Maps but a custom graphic that is scrollable / zoomable using javascript (zynga-scroller). The scrolling / zooming happens via `translate3d` and `scale`.

One layer above the scrollable / zoomable image there are icons and / or popovers that are not transformed via scale, but only with `translate3d` with the coordinates multiplied with the scale.

Because on scroll / zoom the calculation has to be calculated and applied for each element on each frame, on slower devices the map gets a bit slow. Without the icons or only with a few of them it's really fast.

Until now, I had the following idea of optimizing this a bit:

- transformOrigin

  tried setting the coordinates of the icons as transformOrigin, so I would only have to update these values on zoom. This didn't work because transformOrigin seems to only work with percentage values. I could calculate them too if there seems to be no other possibility.

Is there anything else I overlooked? Some property that prevents scale to get applied on certain elements for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I explained my problem properly, but now I found the following solution:

Now I have all the icons in the same container as the map image itself. When you zoom in to zoomlevel `0.3`, `scale(0.3)` gets applied on the container. To leave the icons at the size they were before, I neutralize the scale by applying `scale( 1 / zoomlevel )` to the icons.

This way the style of the icons only needs to be recalculated when zooming and the map feels much more responsive on slower devices, especially when scrolling.